How do I generate and manage a Azure access token for my Springboot Application?
I'm migrating a Spring boot application to Azure that uses R2DBC which does not support passwordless connection. If I use the access token I get from:
az account get-access-token --resource-type oss-rdbms --query "accessToken" -o tsv

And insert in my Pom with
r2dbc:
    url: ${url}
    username:${username}
    password: ${access_token}

Everything works fine, however the access token expires every hour. Is there a way I can generate and manage the token/refresh it in the app itself instead of grabbing this token from command line? Still new to both Spring and Azure, so I'd appreciate the help.
I've tried looking up and creating token controllers as advised by posts I've seen around such as :
Azure Function with Azure AD access token
However I don't have access to Client Secrets at the moment due to company roles. Also since I'm still a bit new to Spring I've been going in circles a bit trying to get everything working so I'm putting this question out while I learn and try things out. This also seemed close but I don't know much about the front end section:
https://medium.com/sopra-steria-norge/how-to-acquire-and-use-an-access-token-from-azure-ad-in-a-react-spring-app-a-simple-developers-fceffa1b7893

You can generate and manage an Azure access token for your Spring Boot application in three ways:
Note : Pom.xml contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project.It cannot Use properties in it.We can Use bash way/application.properties way for using properties .
Firstly by using AzureCliCredential from the Azure Identity Library. Make sure to use az login and az account set before using this code.
Below code is to retrieve an access token by specifying the required resource scope.
package com.example;

import com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredential;
import com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AzureCliCredential credential = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
        
        TokenRequestContext requestContext = new TokenRequestContext()
                .addScopes("https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net/.default"); 

        try {
       
            AccessToken token = credential.getToken(requestContext).block();
            
            if (token != null) {
                String bearerToken = token.getToken();
                System.out.println("Access Token: " + bearerToken); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to retrieve access token.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error retrieving access token: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Output:

Secondly is to use a bash script to set up a configuration file. You can follow the documentation for more details.
mkdir -p src/main/resources && touch src/main/resources/database.properties

cat << EOF > src/main/resources/database.properties
url=jdbc:mysql://${AZ_DATABASE_NAME}.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/demo?sslMode=REQUIRED&serverTimezone=UTC&defaultAuthenticationPlugin=com.azure.identity.extensions.jdbc.mysql.AzureMysqlAuthenticationPlugin&authenticationPlugins=com.azure.identity.extensions.jdbc.mysql.AzureMysqlAuthenticationPlugin
user=${AZ_MYSQL_AD_NON_ADMIN_USERNAME}
EOF


Alternatively, you can configure your database properties in the application.properties file . Refer this doc to use Spring Data R2DBC with different Azure Database
application.properties:
logging.level.org.springframework.data.r2dbc=DEBUG

spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:pool:mysql://$AZ_DATABASE_NAME.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/demo?tlsVersion=TLSv1.2
spring.r2dbc.username=spring-non-admin
spring.r2dbc.password=$AZ_MYSQL_NON_ADMIN_PASSWORD



